# Regex to exlude a particular line if substring matches

Tags: regex

I have been trying to run a regex for some time but cannot get it right. Lets say my file has the following rows:

```
java.SocketException
java.Exception
Exception
RuntimeException
1 RuntimeException`
```

I want to write a regex that will exclude "SocketException" but others should be allowed. A simple egrep -v "SocketException"  works fine. But my regex sits inside a config file, which will be used by another internal program to parse the file.

I have tried multiple things like:

```
egrep '?(!Socket)Exception' my.log
egrep '?!(Socket)Exception' my.log
egrep '(?<!(Socket))Exception' my.log
```

etc.

But i cannot just exclude the SocketException.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards -Amit

Comment: Use `grep -P '(?<!Socket)Exception' my.log`

Comment: I do not have the option to call grep. I just can create the Regex. Having said that,  this works with grep -P. I guess I will have to run with the internal program and see if works there (as i dont know what the internal program calls) i.e. grep -P or egrep. Thanks though.

Comment: What programming language does the _internal program_ have?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```
^(?!.*SocketException).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This expression will find lines which do not contain `SocketException`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/zV1qX7/1

**Sample Text**

```
java.SocketException
java.Exception
Exception
RuntimeException
1 RuntimeException`
```

**Sample Matches**

```
java.Exception
Exception
RuntimeException
1 RuntimeException`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    SocketException          'SocketException'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```